# React state setting timing for conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Currently, I am working on a simple React Exercise.

The I am trying to conditionally render a certain part of the jsx based on a certain state.

Basically, my code looks like this

```
const ShopList = (props) => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [isEnd, setIsEnd] = useState(false)

    const handleButtonClick = ()=>{
        setIsLoading(true)
        axios.get('https://codingapple1.github.io/shop/data2.json')
        .then((result)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>props.addData(result.data),2000)
        })
        .then(()=>{
            setIsEnd(true)
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e)
            setIsLoading(false)
        })
    }

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {props.shoes.map((shoe,i) => (
                    <Product shoe={shoe} ind={i+1} key={shoe.id}/>
                ))}
            </div>
            {isLoading && <h3>Loading....</h3>}
            {!isEnd && <button className="btn btn-light" onClick={handleButtonClick}>More Items</button>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShopList;
```

The thing is that I am having trouble locating my `setIsLoading(false)` so that I can hide the `<h3>Loading...</h3>` after two seconds.

In which part of the `handleButtonClick` function should I put `setIsLoading(false)`?

Comment: What should `isEnd` indicate? Seems to be quite similar to `isLoading`?

Comment: @Mushroomator the isEnd indicates that there are no more contents to load. It is for the button with the class "btn btn-light".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question, you most likely need to hide "Loading" in both cases:
if the request was successful and not.
So you could do this in the `finally` section like this:

```
axios.get(...)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...)
  .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
```

Comment: I've tried your answer, but the "Loading..." message appears only briefly after I press the "More Items" button.....

Comment: I managed to get what I want using setTimeout inside .finally but this kinda isn't the way I wanted to realize what I am trying to make. But thank you.

Comment: @gejyn14 this happening because you do `setTimeout(()=>props.addData(result.data),2000)`. 

What actually happens is that promise first calls the API via `axios`. Right after you have continuation which runs that timer, then you do `setIsEnd(true)`, and then the promise is done, so it runs the `finally` block.

But your data still not updated because you delayed it via `setTimeout`. Are you sure you need to have it right there?